# How Can I test a an action reducer with an async call and dispatch inside using Jest?

Tags: javascript, redux, jestjs

I'm new in Jest and I'm trying to make test to my async action creators. The problem is that I only have seen examples of tests where there is a method for the action creator and other separate method for the dispatch. My actions creators have the dispatch as an async callback function, but I can't figure out how to make the test.
My Action Reducer looks like this:

```
export const postConnection = (connectionUrl, username, password) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const response = await requireAuthActions.post('/db/conexion', JSON.stringify({ connectionUrl, username, password }));
        dispatch({ type: POST_CONNECTION, payload: response.data });
        history.push('/conexiones');
    }
}
```

And I have trying to do the test script but when I run it it throws me an error. The script looks like this:

```
describe('Pruebas de Conexiones', () => {
    describe('Action Creators', () => {
        it("Crear conexión", async () => {
            const dispatch = jest.fn();
            const {data} = await postConnection('www.google.com', 'root', 'password')(dispatch);
            dispatch({});
        });
    });
});
```

And when I try to run the test script it throws me the next error:

```
Request failed with status code 401

      at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at settle (node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
      at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)
```

Is there a way of test actions creators like the mine?

**EDIT**
Now I have a mocks file with a mock for axios that looks like this:

```
const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios');

mockAxios.create = jest.fn(() => mockAxios)

export default mockAxios
```

But now my problems is that I don't know how to implement this in the test file. For now I have something like this:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import mockAxios from 'axios';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

describe('Test de conexiones', () =>{
    describe('Action Creators', () =>{
        it('Agregar conexión', async () =>{
            const store = mockStore({});
            const mockData = {data:123};
            mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(()=>Promise.resolve({data: mockData}));

            const expectedActions = [
                {type: POST_CONNECTION, data: mockData}
            ]
            const dispatch = jest.fn();
            const response = await postConnection('www.google.com','root','password')(dispatch);
        });
    });
});
```

And it throws me the next error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

      12 |     return async (dispatch) => {
      13 |         const response = await requireAuthActions.post('/db/conexion', JSON.stringify({ connectionUrl, username, password }));
    > 14 |         dispatch({ type: POST_CONNECTION, payload: response.data });
         |                                                             ^
      15 |         history.push('/conexiones');
      16 |     }
      17 | }
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  Have you tried using your `jest.fn()` as a test spy?  As a rule, your tests shouldn't call external services, so you'll want to mock out that response too, forget the whole async/await approach.

Comment: @jmargolisvt i have updated my question with the error log.

Comment: you did not mock your API so it calls real server with incomplete data. better mock it.

Comment: @jmargolisvt something like this? `expect(dispatch.mock.calls).toEqual(data);`

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 approaches possible: using real store or [`redux-mock-store`](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store)

Steps are similar:

1. Set up store.
2. mock external API like http call or at least `requireAuthActions` module with some response(successful or failed)(check [jest's docs on mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks))
3. make a pause to await(`await Promise.resolve();`, [`flush-promises`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises) or `setTimeout(..., 0)`) all async things like `Promise.resolve()` you mocked in #2.
4. if you use real store - then check against store(with selectors if you use this level of abstraction) if it contains data you would expect to see based on response you mocked in #2
5. if it's `redux-mock-store` you cannot verify data in state(so reducers should be tested separately) so just validate list of actions generated - if they meet expectations based on response mocked in #2 or not.

Comment: How can I do the mock? I have tryied creating a folder called __mock__ and adding an axios.js file inside it with this code `get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))` but is not running.

Comment: folder should be named of `__mocks__` for [mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks). Also we may use [automocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) just simple as `jest.mock('axios');` Check both links for a bunch of examples.

Comment: I have changed the mock and now it is like this `const mockAxios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios');
mockAxios.create = jest.fn(() => mockAxios)
export default mockAxios` but now I don't know how to implement this mock in the test file

Comment: I have updated my answer with the new mock and how I tried to implement it in the test file. I still don't know how to implement the mock for the test.

Comment: have you checked with debugger that your mock is called properly?